# Spectral radius of a time-varying matrix with strictly positive increment

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Consider a time varying non-negative matrix $A(t)$ and its spectral radius $\rho(A(t))$ where $t$ denotes the time. If $A(t)$ changes over time with each time a random element in $A(t)$ is being increased by a random value, will the spectral radius be monotonously increasing over time as well?

In other words, can I say that:

$\rho(A(1))\leq\rho(A(2))\ldots\leq\rho(A(N))$

If yes, how do I proof this?

If no, why?